# return the class= value of an HTML element using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have isolated this element from a webpage using BeautifulSoup and by looping through all the buttons on the webpage...

```
b = 
"""
<button class="D_pV M_ln D_qB D_qj M_l_ D_qe M_lv D_qG D_Ju" type="button">Show more results</button>

"""
```

I simply want to return D_pV M_ln D_qB D_qj M_l_ D_qe M_lv D_qG D_Ju from above.

the closest I've gotten to accomplishing this is using b["class"], but I imagine there's a simpler way?

Comment: Either `' '.join(b['class'])` or [`multi_valued_attributes = None`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Using `b["class"]` and then joining the results is the correct approach, it's already fairly simple.

You will need to parse the isolated element and then join the list of classes into a single string.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Sample HTML
b = """
<button class="D_pV M_ln D_qB D_qj M_l_ D_qe M_lv D_qG D_Ju" type="button">Show more results</button>
"""

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(b, 'html.parser')

# Find the button
button = soup.find('button')

# Get the classes as a string
class_string = " ".join(button["class"])

print(class_string)
```